# Reference collapsing rules not applying as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, perfect-forwarding, reference-collapsing

I am refreshing my memory on how perfect forwarding works in C++. I realize that a call to `std::forward` is forced to provide an explicit template parameter for a reason (i. e. when dealing with rvalue references that are actually lvalues), however when doing a sanity check on actual code, I was surprised by this (somewhat related) scenario:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
T&& fwd(T& t) {
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

template<class T>
T&& fwd(T&& t) {
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

int main()
{
    int lnum = 3;
    if (std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(fwd(lnum))>::value)
        std::cout << "It's rref." << std::endl;           // this get's printed on screen 
    else
        std::cout << "It's lref." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If I understand reference collapsing correctly (and I believe I do), type deduction should go like this:

```
int& && fwd(int& & t) {                        
    return static_cast<int& &&>(t);         
}
```

leading to

```
int& fwd(int& t) {                        
    return static_cast<int&>(t);         
}
```

Clearly that's not the case. What am I missing here?

Comment: In your case `fwd(T& t)` is called, so `T` is `int`, and as the result you have `int&&`. `fwd(T&)` is better matched than `fwd(T&&)`. So there is no place for reference colllpasing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, no referencing collapsing occurs. The relevant function template to pay attention to, i.e., the one selected, is:

```
template<class T>
T&& fwd(T& t) { // <-- not a forwarding reference
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

Note that this function template has **no** *forwarding references* – the function parameter, `t`, is just an *lvalue reference* (`T& t`).

The `T` template parameter is deduced to **`int`** – not `int&` – because `t` is not a forwarding reference but just an lvalue reference. If you simply replace `T` by `int` in the function template above, then you will obtain:

```
template<class T>
int&& fwd(int& t) {
    return static_cast<int&&>(t);
}
```

No reference collapsing is applied as there is no such a thing here that would otherwise end up becoming *a reference to a reference* (e.g., `int& &&` or `int&& &&`).

Comment: For some reason I extrapolated reference collapsing from forwarding references to *all* references. Feels incredibly silly. Thank you for the correction :)

Comment: @TuRtoise *reference collapsing* applies when the deduced code would otherwise result in a *reference to a reference* – which cannot exist in C++. However, this is regardless of whether or not you are using *forwarding references*. For example, if you call `fwd()` as `fwd<int&>(lnum)`, then `T` will be `int&` and reference collapsing will happen: the return type `int& &&` will collapse into `int&`. You can check that the return type is an lvalue reference because the assignment `fwd<int&>(lnum) = 0;` does compile. Neither `fwd<int>(lnum) = 0;` nor `fwd<int&&>(lnum) = 0;` compile (rvalue ref).

Comment: @mdx What I think you may have extrapolated is type deduction rules for forwarding reference to lvalue references, but not reference collapsing. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: It is, turns out I didn't understand the subject correctly. I'm glad I asked. Once again big thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the function that is called is `T&& fwd(T& t)`. As such, there is no forwarding reference parameter. The parameter is an lvalue reference and the deduced `T` is `int`. As such, there are no references to collapse and the static cast produces `int&&`.

If the called function had been `T&& fwd(T&& t)` (i.e. if the better matching overload didn't exist), then your explanation of reference collapsing would be correct (except for the parameter which would be `int& &&` which also collapses `int&`) and the return type would indeed be lvalue reference.

Comment: Great answer. However I do like the one I accepted a bit more, because I kind of digested it a bit faster. Nevertheless, thanks.